# How to use data validation and 'no filter' in excel

Tags: excel

I'm currently trying to set up some filtering using data validation.
One thing I can do is have the string "<>&" to mean any non-empty value i.e. to do no filtering.

This works when used in a `countifs()` formula.
for example the number of brown dogs formula here is: `=COUNTIFS(O10:O18,R5,P10:P18,R6)` where R6 is currently 'dog' in blue but can be <>& this is working fine.

**What I would like to do next is:**

Count the number of unique owners for a given filter configuration,
for example I would like to know how many unique owners have a brown dog?

There are 4 brown dogs, but two of those dogs are owned by the same owner ID (2), so the answer should be 3 i.e. the unique owner ID's matching the query are 2, 4, 5.

I tried various things with `SUM(COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER()))` but it seems the wild card for default or 'no filter'  "<>&" does not work with the FILTER() function.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to solved this in the end.
effectively `Filter()` cannot understand `"<>&"` as a wildcard so instead we add an if statement to check for that, then to check if an item is in the list we do `ISNUMBER(MATCH())`

Here's the full expression for the cell below [image] and the output:

```
=SUM(COUNTA(UNIQUE(FILTER(L10:L18, (IF($R$6="<>&", TRUE, ISNUMBER(MATCH(P10:P18,$R$6,0))))*(IF($R$5="<>&", TRUE, ISNUMBER(MATCH(O10:O18,$R$5,0))))))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Expand your Countifs to add "include" where=1 and you will have your count of 3.

Comment: sorry the include column is a red herring that column is not used at all in any calculations sorry for the confusion. I was trying to illustrate the set-up of multiple filters.